# How can I change to my working copy in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

With "Show log" and "Update item to revision" I switched to my previous commit.

Now I want to switch back to my working copy? How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run [`svn update`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/#svn.tour.cycle.update) or [SVN Update in TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-update.html). This will update your working copy items to the most recent revision (i.e. **HEAD**)

Comment: I want to switch to my working copy which I haven't committed yet.

Comment: @Nadine uncommitted changes are not versioned, you cannot restore them unless you committed them to the repository or saved in another manner.

Comment: @Nadine I don't think that uncommited local changes disappear just for updating to an older revision. If that really happened, they're gone.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought I could easily switch between older revisions and my working copy. But when I switched to the latest revision it merged my working copy code with the latest revision and the previous one. I had to manually delete the unwanted code and now I can work with my working copy again.